# node.js, TCP sockets, and docker - why connection reset by peer with more than 32 concurrent connections?

Tags: node.js, sockets, docker, tcp, docker-for-mac

I am completely new to Docker as of yesterday.  I have this node.js server that I am running that simply creates a TCP server and then handles messages coming in from a client. There is a test harness that was written by someone else that I have been running that allows for as many concurrent connections as you want.

When I run it locally, I can have 100+ concurrent connections no problem.  I do however see a problem locally sometimes when I start to do 200+ concurrent connections, and it actually hits the `socket.on(error)` case and gives me an error.  If I start the server right up though, and try 200 concurrent connections, it usually successfully completes, but subsequent tries will error out.

However when I run the harness with the server running in Docker, as soon as I try to run it with 33 concurrent connections, it does not work.  I get a "connection reset by peer" error from the test harness.  If I try 32 connections, it works fine.  When I try 33+, I also do not see any error on the server, as I did when running locally.  If I try doing 32 concurrent connections again after it fails with 33+, it will succeed just fine.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?  Is there some sort of setting within Docker I have to change to allow more than 32 concurrent connections?  I find it interesting that it's a hard limit of 32 and always works with 32 and never works with 33.

FWIW, in my node.js server, I have it listening on `port 8080` and `host 0.0.0.0`.  Initially I had it on `127.0.0.1` but while that worked locally, it would not work in Docker.  To run it, I'm using the command `docker run -p 8080:8080 app`.

I am running Docker on my MacBook Pro running the latest OSX.

Any ideas?

Comment: What platform are you running Docker on? What does your app do processing wise? What happens if you run the test harness in the container or in another container on the same docker network?

Comment: I am running on OSX (updated my post).  The app reads messages coming from a client connected via TCP socket and writes a message to the client of either success, failure, or error based on what happens.  I have not tried running the harness from Docker yet so maybe that is a good next step.  The test harness is an executable so I'll have to figure out how to do that with Docker.

Comment: There are some [fundamental differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679503/1318694) between testing on local host and in a Docker for Mac VM, but it shouldn't be that severe

Comment: In that question, op mentions "Reset to factory defaults" helped.